# .htaccess for addon domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, add-on

I have www.a.com (main), and addon domain www.b.com

Structure directory domain b is www.a.com/b.com

i want to make .htaccess setting :
`www.b.com/prod_detail.php?Code=200` and be `www.b.com/prod_detail/200`

if i sett like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^prod_detail/([0-9][0-9])/$ /prod_detail.php?Code=$1
```

not working. 
Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would only match 2 digit numbers, how about this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^prod_detail/(\d+)$ /prod_detail.php?Code=$1
```

Comment: if you put the rule in a .htaccess file, and your server allows rewrites, it will take effect instantly

Comment: I've asked to the hosting. They say the setting is on.
Is there a difference for the setting. Htaccess primary domain and addon domain? until now still not working. Please help..Thank